# Limit text to a certain number of chars, but stop when a period is found within the final 20 chars

Tags: php, text, punctuation

So, I have this function to produce an excerpt from large texts.

```php
function excerpt( $string, $max_chars = 160, $more = '...' ) {

    if ( strlen( $string ) > $max_chars ) {

        $cut = substr( $string, 0, $max_chars );

        $string = substr( $cut, 0, strrpos( $cut, ' ' ) ) . $more;

    }

  return $string;
}
```

This works just fine for it's intends - it limits a given text to a certain number of chars, without cutting words.

**Here's a working example**:

```php
$str = "The best things in using PHP are that it is extremely simple for a newcomer, but offers many advanced features for a professional programmer. Don't be afraid reading the long list of PHP's features. You can jump in, in a short time, and start writing simple scripts in a few hours.";

echo excerpt( $str, 160 );
```

**This produces this output**:

> The best things in using PHP are that it is extremely simple for a newcomer, but offers many advanced features for a professional programmer. Don't be afraid...

However, I'm trying to figure out **how to stop if a period, an exclamation or an interrogation mark is found** within the excerpts last 20 chars. So, using the above sentence, it would produce this output:

> The best things in using PHP are that it is extremely simple for a newcomer, but offers many advanced features for a professional programmer.

Any ideas how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following and put this in a loop for all of your:

```
// Define the characters to look for:
$charToCheck = array(".", "!", "?");

// Loop through each character to check
foreach ( $charToCheck as $char) {

    // Gives you the last index of a period. Returns false if not in string
    $lastIndex = strrpos($cut, $char);

    // Checks if character is found in the last 20 characters of your string
    if ( $lastIndex > ($max_chars - 20)) {
        // Returns the shortened string beginning from first character
        $cut = substr($cut, 0, $lastIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use something a bit faster, couldn't find any. I could not do it with preg_split(), that was my idea at first. Your code works, I've just rewrite it in order to optimize it and to exit the loop on first match. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Same approach as Fuzzzel's answer, but exits loop returning substr (without '...') on first match.

```
function excerpt( $string, $max_chars = 160, $more = '...' ) {

    $punct = array('.', '!', '?');  // array of punctuation chars to stop on

    if ( strlen( $string ) > $max_chars ) {

        $cut = substr( $string, 0, $max_chars );

        $string = substr( $cut, 0, strrpos( $cut, ' ' ) );

        foreach( $punct as $stop ){
            $stop_pos = stripos( $string, $stop, $max_chars - 20 );
            if( $stop_pos !== false){
                return substr( $string, 0, $stop_pos + 1);
            }
        }
    }

  return $string . $more;
}

$str = "The best things in using PHP are that it is extremely simple for a newcomer, but offers many advanced features for a professional programmer! Don't be afraid reading the long list of PHP's features. You can jump in, in a short time, and start writing simple scripts in a few hours.";

echo excerpt( $str, 160 );
```

Comment: I rewrote Fuzzzel's code with the same thing in mind. However I've accepted his answer as correct, since he gave the initial idea. Thank you very much.